# How to calculate a multivariable fisher information matrix

Tags: fisher-information, fisher-scoring

I do not understand what is the definition for
$$\mathcal I(\theta) = -E[H(\theta)]$$
where $H$ is the hessian of log-likelihood function
how should I calculate this if $\theta$ is a vector. What should be the formula
to calculate it as a single variable formula (without any vectors inside the formula)

Comment: The $(i,j)$th element of the Fisher’s information would be $-E[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta_i \partial \theta_j} \log f(X ; \theta)]$.

Comment: @DaeyoungLim The hardest part for this is expectation, not sure what is the meaning of $E$ for a matrix

Comment: apply the expectation elementwise

Comment: @DaeyoungLim but $\theta$ is multivariate how to calculate the expectation for multivariate and what is the pdf to integrate in this case. Is it $f$ or $\log f$ or the resulting hessian matrix element function and with respect to which variable. Could you provide a formula if possible?